# how to convert date to timestamp?

Tags: web-server, time

How should I convert date format(dd-mm-yyyy) to timestamp value . Can anyone suggest code how to convert and where to put code .

Comment: What do you mean by "timestamp value"? And how should we know where to put that resulting code? And what have you tried so far? Where do you use it with Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

It is good for you?

```
struct tm tm;
time_t fecha;
if ( strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm) != NULL )
  fecha = mktime(&tm);
else 

// Another thing
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino.SE. To increase the benefit of all users looking at your post, you should add some explanation to your code. Consider a lot of the users here newbies. At least add some comments in your code.